# Matrix given as difference between two lists

Tags: python, matrix

I would need help constructing a matrix. There are two vectors given, one with dimension a = (40,1) and the other b = (50,1). I need to construct a matrix like this:

*A = [[a1-b1, a1-b2, a1-b3,..., a1-b50], [a2-b1, a2-b1, a3-b3,...,a2-b50],..., [a40-b1, a40-b2, a40-b3,..., a40-b50]]*.

Can someone please explain to me how to do it?

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code-writing service. Please read [ask] and how to write a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your "vectors" are `numpy` arrays, this should work:

```
A = a - b.T
```

Here:

- `b.T` represents the transpose of `b`, and has shape `(1, 50)`
- `a - b.T` will result in [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.broadcasting.html) of both `a` and `b.T`
- After broadcasting, element-wise subtraction happens between the two arrays that result from the broadcasting.